# it is possible to access an object field in DynamoDB ExpressionAttributeNames?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, dynamodb-queries

I am trying to make a ConditionExpression in DynamoDB Update with a field from my item object.

My update params is:

```
{
  TableName: 'Item',
  Key: { id: '232323' },
  ExpressionAttributeNames: {
    '#name': 'name',
    '#ownerId': 'owner.id'
  },
  ExpressionAttributeValues: {
    ':name': 'new name',
    ':scanOwnerId': '121212'
  },
  UpdateExpression: 'SET  #name = :name',
  ConditionExpression: '#ownerId = :scanOwnerId'
}
```

Comment: owner is a nested object inside Item.

Comment: Item is like: {"id":"123", name: "Foo", "owner": {"id": "345"}}